# google-cloud-speech Medical Pre-Built Models

Tags: google-cloud-speech

does anyone know if the google-cloud-speech recognition has a Medical Special Module ?

in advance, Thanks
Asaf Elkabets
M.A.R LTD

Comment: This sounds like a job for Web Search Person, hero of the internets!

Answer (score 0):

There is no special modules in Speech API. You can use [Enhanced Models](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/enhanced-models) to get access to a special set of machine learning models for speech recognition or [Cloud Machine Learning Engine](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/technical-overview) to build your own model.